# magento how to make shipping method shown up but not selectable

Tags: magento-1.9

i am creating my own shipping method extension.
how to make a shipping method shown up but not selectable (disabled)?
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is somehow unclear. Why would you need a fake shipping method? Can you give a scenario?

Comment: sorry for not being unclear. in some case, my shipping method is disabled and magento hide it. i want it to be shown up but the INPUT should has disabled property to disable it. just to let my customers know that this method exists but not available for the current cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up disabling the method using javascript instead of php way.